# Sentence Construction in English

Tags: sentence-construction

Context ,
My friend told me that he would go to his  native tomorrow.
Next day another friend asked me about his were about .
I said like this

"He was going to his native. But I m not sure that he has gone or not."

Or

"He was about to go to his native ......."

Let me if I correctly said or not.

Comment: This question, as it stands, is a request for proof-reading, which is off-topic on this site, so I'm closing this question. If you want to know about a specific aspect of English, like the grammar or vocabulary you're unsure about, please edit it to make that clear, then use the "Reopen" button to get it opened to new answers again

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, you don't use "native" as a noun like that. If you mean that your friend was going to where he was born, you could say something like "He said he was going to the country/place/town where he was born".

As for the second sentence you said, it would be slightly better to say "I'm not sure whether he has gone or not."

Comment: Plz help me with full sentences

Answer (score 1):

“Native” is primarily an adjective meaning “pertaining to the place of birth.” It is derived from the Latin word “natus,” which is a passive participle of the Latin verb meaning “be born.”

“Native” is also used as a noun meaning a “person born in.” So, a “native of Bangladesh” means a person born in Bangladesh even if that person is currently a citizen of the U.S. resident in Italy.

> He said he was going to his native

makes no sense at all. It is not idiomatic. Presumably what is meant is

> He said he was going to his native country

As to your other question, what would be more idiomatic, at least in American English, is to replace “that” with “whether,” but “that” is grammatically acceptable.